# Why $ \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n}A/(p^{\alpha_{j}})\cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^{m}A/(p^{\beta_{j}})$ implies $n=m$ and $\alpha_{j}=\beta_{j}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> A is PID, $p$ is a prime in A and $1\leq \alpha_{1}\leq\ldots\leq \alpha_{n},\;1\leq \beta_{1}\leq\ldots\leq \beta_{m}$. We are given that $$ \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n}A/(p^{\alpha_{j}})\cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^{m}A/(p^{\beta_{j}})$$
> Prove that $n=m$ and $\alpha_{j}=\beta_{j}$.

I couldn't find a theory about all this stuff (well, there were some books, but I wasn't satisfied); from the first look I thought that one could use something about basis, however there is no basis in $A/(p^{\alpha_{j}})$ (if $\alpha_{j}>1$?). Could you give any hint?

Comment: This is in "every" textbook on basic algebra, it is a step to prove the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID. What do you mean you "couldn't find a theory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ denote the direct sum.  Then for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$, we have $Mp^k/Mp^{k+1}$ is a vector space over $A/p$, of dimension $d_k$.

We have $d_k=\#\{j| \alpha_j<k\}=\#\{j| \beta_j<k\}$ for all $k$, as required.

Comment: I have got the same result about vector space, but was not sure if I was right. Thanks!